# NullReference Exception error

Tags: vb.net, exception, null

I dont know what is wrong in my program the exception in my program is cmd.commandtext until in the model.text

> NullReference Exception was unhandled Object variable or With block
>   variable not set

```
Private Sub btnadd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
   ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnadd.Click

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim tablelist As New DataTable
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Open()
    End If
    cmd.Connection = con

    If Me.stcode.Tag & "" = "" Then
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Database11(stcode, description, company, department, location, user, serial number, date purchased, tagable, quantity, brand, model ) " & _
                        " VALUES(" & Me.stcode.Text & ",'" & Me.des.Text & "','" & _
                            Me.com.Text & "','" & Me.dep.Text & "','" & Me.loc.Text & "','" & _
                            Me.user.Text & "','" & Me.user.Text & "','" & Me.sn.Text & "','" & _
                            Me.dp.Text & "','" & Me.Tag.Text & "','" & Me.quan.Text & "','" & _
                            Me.brand.Text & "','" & Me.model.Text & "')"

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(cmd.CommandText, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: where does it throws that exaption?

Comment: You don't say which line your exception happens on, though I'm guessing it's the huge horrible mess of inline Sql (I'd suggest you read about Sql injection, and parameterised queries and then rewrite this code...). Also: this exception is simple to diagnose and fix. You should be able to work this out by reading the error message and debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the `Tag` property of your `stcode` control is null (`Nothing`). Put a check for null, like this:

```
If strcode.Tag IsNot Nothing Then

End If
```

So your code should now read:

```
If strcode.Tag IsNot Nothing Then
    If Me.stcode.Tag & "" = "" Then
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Database11(stcode, description, company, department, location, user, serial number, date purchased, tagable, quantity, brand, model ) " & _
                    " VALUES(" & Me.stcode.Text & ",'" & Me.des.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.com.Text & "','" & Me.dep.Text & "','" & Me.loc.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.user.Text & "','" & Me.user.Text & "','" & Me.sn.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.dp.Text & "','" & Me.Tag.Text & "','" & Me.quan.Text & "','" & _
                        Me.brand.Text & "','" & Me.model.Text & "')"

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(cmd.CommandText, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
End If
```